# Why won't my codeigniter model load?

Tags: codeigniter, model, loading

Here's my model:

```
   <?php

   class Dbtest extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }


    function getAll() {
        parent::Model();
        $this->db->select('title, content');
        $this->db->from('posts');
        $this->db->where('post_id', 1);

        $q = $this->db->get();

        if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
   }
```

Here's my controller:

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Dbtest extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $this->load->model('dbtest');
        $data['rows'] = $this->dbtest->getAll();

        $this->load->view('dbtest', $data); 
    }
   }
```

And here's my view

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

   <html>
      <head>
      <title></title>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>

     <body>
    <div id="container">
        <p>My view has been loaded</p>
        <?php foreach($rows as $r) : ?>

        <h1><?php echo $r->title; ?></h1>
        <div><?php echo $r->content; ?></div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
     </body>
   </html>
```

I keep getting a 500 server error. What could I possibly be doing wrong. I have autoloaded the database library. Please help a codeigniter newbie trying to learn this great framework.

Comment: `I keep getting a 500 server error` You (practically) can't develop web applications if you don't have access to the access/error logs.

Comment: good suggestion leon - could you tell me where I would find these logs?

Comment: That depends on your web server configuration (Apache, IIS?). For example (Apache, Fedora Linux) `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.  BTW, I hope that you are developing in a local (developer) machine.

Comment: Yes I am developing on my local machine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function getAll() {
    parent::Model();   //<-------------------Remove this line
    $this->db->select('title, content');
    $this->db->from('posts');
```

After taking a quick look, why is this line there?

It is a php4 constructor call to the old version of the Model base class that no longer exists..

remove and try again.

**EDIT**

Also, you cannot name a model AND Controller the same name, they have namespace conflicts.

call the model `Dbtest_model` or something and use it that way.

Also, this is unnecessary

```
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

`$q->result()` returns an array, no need to loop through and rebuild... Just do this...

```
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $q->result();
    }
```

Comment: Tried this but I just get a HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error):  An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request. I am on MAMP localhost running PHP 5.3+

Comment: While we're shooting in the dark here, you cannot have controllers and models with the same name.  try that.

Comment: Oh - I did not know that, jon. Will give that a shot

Comment: This Worked finally. Controller and Model cannot have the same name. This isn't really mentioned anywhere. Also found my error logs that said: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Dbtest in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cidemo/application/models/dbtest.php on line 23

Thanks jon. Thanks everyone for their help.

Answer (score 1):

Well after some pretty crappy stuff... I finally found that the problem was in my desition to put some Vars after the

```
class CI_model{}
```

in the Core Model (application/system/core/Model) of my CI application, just for the goods of autocompletion for Eclipse/aptana/netbeans. So if you can revert back to normal from a clean CI installation, i think it should get back to normal, this was my final solution. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you call `parent::CI_Model();` instead of `parent::__construct();`?

Ci is designed to work on php4, and `__construct()` wasn't added until php5.

Comment: Incorrect, CI 2.0.x holds a php5 requirement...  and uses the `CI_` prefix